# PL/SQL Insert com cursor

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, oracle12c

Galera, boa tarde.

Tenho 2 tabelas, uma de `foro_tribunal` e outra de `vara`
Na tabela de `vara`, preciso incluir 111 registros por `foro_tribunal`, então, criei um `foro_tribunal` como modelo pra copiar pros outros `foro_tribunais` quando percorrer no loop. Segue o código:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
    V_FORO_MODELO     NUMBER (019) := 12057 ;--MODELO A SER COPIADO(FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID);
    V_USUARIO         NUMBER(019);--USUARIO_ID
    SQ_VARA           NUMBER(019);

    CURSOR CURSOR_FORO_TRIBUNAL IS
        SELECT FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID FROM FORO_TRIBUNAL WHERE FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID <> V_FORO_MODELO AND FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID IN (564) ; --PARA(FORO_tRIBUNAL_ID)

    CURSOR CURSOR_VARA IS
        SELECT VARA_ID,NOME,ORGANIZATION_ID,status FROM VARA WHERE FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID =  V_FORO_MODELO;

BEGIN
    V_USUARIO := 2;
    SQ_VARA := VARA_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

    FOR CFT IN CURSOR_FORO_TRIBUNAL LOOP
        FOR CV IN CURSOR_VARA LOOP
            INSERT INTO VARA(VARA_ID,DATA_REGISTRO,NOME,STATUS,FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USUARIO_ID) 
            VALUES(SQ_VARA,SYSDATE,CV.NOME,CV.STATUS,CFT.FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID,CV.ORGANIZATION_ID,V_USUARIO);
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Porém, quando eu executo, da o erro :

> Relatório de erros - ORA-00001: restrição exclusiva
>   (SYSTEM.SYS_C007029) violada ORA-06512: em line 18
>   00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
>   *Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
>              For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
>              this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
>   *Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Qual alteração devo realizar pra que execute sem erros ?

Comment: sem ver a estrutura das tabelas não dá pra responder, mas o erro é bem claro, tentou inserir mais de um valor com a mesma chave. Antes do insert, tente usar um `dbms_output.put_line` para listar os valores que estão sendo usandos no insert e veja onde está duplicando

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo !
Apenas inclui o SQ_VARA := VARA_SEQ.NEXTVAL; dentro do loop e deu tudo certo. Estava incluindo os 111 itens pro mesmo Id, mas agora deu certo. Vlw !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
    V_FORO_MODELO     NUMBER (019) := 12057 ;--MODELO A SER COPIADO(FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID);
    V_USUARIO         NUMBER(019);--USUARIO_ID
    SQ_VARA           NUMBER(019);
    V_CONTADOR        NUMBER(019);
    CURSOR CURSOR_FORO_TRIBUNAL IS
        SELECT FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID FROM FORO_TRIBUNAL WHERE FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID <> V_FORO_MODELO AND FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID;
    CURSOR CURSOR_VARA IS
        SELECT VARA_ID,NOME,ORGANIZATION_ID,status FROM VARA WHERE FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID =  V_FORO_MODELO;  
BEGIN
    V_USUARIO := 2;
    V_CONTADOR:= 0;
    FOR CFT IN CURSOR_FORO_TRIBUNAL LOOP
        FOR CV IN CURSOR_VARA LOOP
            SQ_VARA := VARA_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
           INSERT INTO VARA(VARA_ID,DATA_REGISTRO,NOME,STATUS,FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USUARIO_ID)  VALUES(SQ_VARA,SYSDATE,CV.NOME,CV.STATUS,CFT.FORO_TRIBUNAL_ID,CV.ORGANIZATION_ID,V_USUARIO);
           V_CONTADOR:= V_CONTADOR+1;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Qtd Inserida: '|| V_CONTADOR);
END;
```